# Is dynamic_cast each call more expensive than a cached var with null check?

Tags: c++, casting

For a function in a class that is to be called 100 times a second or more, for long periods of time (many hours), which of the following is a better approach in terms of performance?

1. using `dynamic cast` to cast the var to the required type each time the function is called:

   ```
   Foo()
   {
     TypeA* A = dynamic_cast<TypeA>(B);
     // do something with A
   }
   ```
2. cache the result of the cast to a variable of the required type, cast only if the cache is null, and use the cache otherwise:

   ```
   Foo()
   {
     TypeA* A = GetCachedA();
     // do something with A
   }

   TypeA* GetCachedA()
   {
     if(CachedA == nullptr)
       CachedA = dynamic_cast<TypeA>(B);
     return CachedA;
   }
   ```

The difference may be marginal to some, but keep in mind that its a performance critical scenario, and every drop of performance matters.

Comment: If it is of interest to you, write some code to benchmark it.

Comment: If you already know that the type is correct just do a `static_cast`, which is free. If there's the possibility that it isn't, then your cache is performing a failing `dynamic_cast` each time in these cases.

Comment: Expanding the interface with a few extra virtual functions so that you do not care what the type is is out of the question?

Comment: `dynamic_cast` usually means something is badly designed. I don't remember last time I had to use it.

Comment: @MarekR Oh really? what would you do when the interface supplies you with a base class as parameter but you need act differently depending on what the actual type is. You are not going to suggest cluttering the base class with all possible child functions are you? or would you suggest different interface for each possible child class?

Comment: `you need act differently depending on what the actual type is` - this is definition of bad design.

Comment: @MarekR: No, it's not. It's what virtual functions do, and it's what the visitor pattern does. It can be a problem, but we don't know enough to say that it is at all--it can be (and often is) entirely reasonable.

Comment: @MarekR nope, that's your personal opinion a lot of state of the art software framework make use of downcasting and its the norm. You cannot package your class's interface to be compatible with every possible extension of it in the future perhaps what you are saying occurs only in very basic and limited design

Comment: @JerryCoffin but he used this sentence in context of dynamic_cast. Do you use dynamic cast in visitor pattern?

Comment: @MarekR: Yes, I read what he said. Of course neither virtual functions nor the visitor pattern (at least normally) involve a `dynamic_cast`. But behavior that varies with the class involved can be and often is reasonable. There may be room for question whether his use of it is reasonable, but we don't know enough  to say it isn't.

Comment: @Allahjane 1) "_a lot of state of the art software framework make use of downcasting and its the norm_" Such as?  If something is wildly used (overused), it doesn't matter that it is good design. Typically such miss-designs happen due to being too lazy to think of a good design, or due to historical reasons. 2) It's hard to suggest something design-related without seeing the full picture, but, you, typically, define virtual methods, that makes sense, on a base class, and use those wherever you have only a base class. You override those virtual methods, in case you want custom class logic.

Comment: I'm going to sit in the avoid if possible camp. If it's a few general functions, and you can edit the interface, add a few virtual functions. If you have to add a dozen, or can't add anything, consider something else. Stuff like `goto` is still in the language because every now and then it is the right answer.

Comment: May not fit your use case, but what about `TypeA* GetCachedA() { static TypeA * CachedA = dynamic_cast<TypeA>(B); return CachedA; }`?

Comment: This question is about performance. Did you do a profiling before blaming `dynamic_cast`? Are you sure this is source of performance issues. I'm not saying it is not. From experience I know that newbies are often try optimize part of code responsible for 1% of CPU time.

Answer (score 2):

When I've tested this (admittedly, not recently) a `dynamic_cast` was expensive enough that it favored caching the pointer. But that was my test on an obsolete machine in a situation that was different from yours.

At the time, I used a slightly different basic design though. Instead of checking for a null pointer, I used a pointer to a function (could have used a virtual function instead...) that was initialized to point to a function that did the dynamic cast, saved the result, then (the crucial part) overwrote the function pointer with the address of a function that just returned the cached pointer.

That added a little extra overhead when adding the pointer to the cache, but reduced it (quite a bit) on subsequent uses. At least in my testing, it was a win as long as you used the pointer at least three times (but, here again, your mileage may and probably will vary).